# How to package ruby application

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How do you package a ruby app so all the dependencies are already packaged in the app and does not require the user to be messing about with bundler or rvm.

Comment: What platform? What kind of app?

Comment: Mainly osx, but it's just a command line app, just dont want the user to be messing about with bundler ect just run the commands.

Answer (score 2):

Use "require" for all the dependencies you need in an ordered manner.
However the require only works if the "required" package is installed on the machine. from what I know there is no automated tool .. and how do you know even "ruby" is installed (non-MacOS).

If you don't want user to "mess" with installing anything -- then you have to write a piece of code that checks the presence of dependencies and installs them if needed. .. best is to write the install script in install script/program with bash etc. or in ruby inline with something with try/end syntax.